# Swing: MouseListener only on ImageIcon not JLabel

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have a Java Swing application with a `JFrame` containing a `JLabel` containing an `ImageIcon`.
I want to monitor the mouse entering/exiting the `ImageIcon`.

For now I use the `addMouseListener` method of `JLabel` but the event Entered & Exited are thrown only when I enter/exit the application's window, not the `ImageIcon`.

I see no `addMouseListener` method for `ImageIcon`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Probably the `JLabel` is stretched to fill the whole `JFrame` ,that's why `mouseListener` is activated when the mouse enters the `JFrame`. ***[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size)*** post may help you to fix it.

Comment: 1) Is there text in the label? 2)  What layout & constraint.. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Take a look at **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871530/java-imageicons-and-actioin-listeners/15871783#15871783)** which demonstrates a method of detecting mouse over on images based on the image's pixel alpha levels

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for possible solutions to the problem referenced by @ExtremeCoders

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah, you caught me showing off ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Java Swing application with a JFrame containing a JLabel
>   containing an ImageIcon. I want to monitor the mouse entering/exiting
>   the ImageIcon.

- agreed, in [Icon / ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) isn't implemented any mouse or key event
- [half workaround in ym question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java/7944388#7944388)
- best of options is to [use un_decorated JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)